# a function produces an inifinite loop

Tags: c

I wrote the following function and when I run it , it produces an infinite loop and I dont understand why.

This function creates a dynamic array of dynamic strings. Every such string starts with  a letter given, or with a capital letter which is compatible to the letter given:

```
void wordsStartWithLetter(char letter, char *str,char***newstr,int *numOfWords) 
{
    int i=0, count=0;
    char *word;
    char *delimiter = " ";

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i]==letter ||str[i]==(letter-32 )) //if it founds the letter at the begining of the word, than run till the space//
        {
            while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0' ) 
              i++;      //counting the number of words beginng with the letter given//
            count++;        
        }
        else
        {
            while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0' ) 
                i++;
        }
    }

    *newstr = (char**)malloc (sizeof(char*)*count); 
    *numOfWords=count;
    i=0;

    word = strtok(str, delimiter);      //we use strtok to separate each word from the origin string//

    while(word!=NULL)            
    {
        if (word[0]==letter ||word[0]==letter-32)
        {
            (*newstr)[i]=word;                 //insert the compatible words into the new 2D-string//
            i++;
        }
        word = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

}
```

I call that  function the by the following way:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define SIZE 50

void Ex();
void wordsStartWithLetter(char letter, char *str,char***newstr,int *numOfWords) ;

void main()
{

    Ex();
}

void Ex()
{
    char ch;
    char str[SIZE];
    char **newstr;
    int numOfWords,i;

    printf("please enter a string: ");
    _flushall();
    gets(str);
    printf("plese enter a letter: " );
    _flushall();
    ch=_getche();
    wordsStartWithLetter(ch, str,&newstr,&numOfWords);

    ("the words of the origin string which start which %c :\n",ch);
    for(i=0;i<numOfWords;i++)
        printf("%s\n",newstr[i]);

    for (i=0;i<numOfWords; i++)
       free(newstr[i]);
    free(newstr);
}
```

Comment: How do you call the function? Show a [mcve] please.

Comment: If your `while (str[i] != '\0')` loop hits a `' '` it does not increment `i` anymore, so it will run forever.

Comment: Debug, put print of valors inside your code to know where it loops. Also avoid casting the result of malloc.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't duplicate code; just move the while loop out of the if/else: `if(... == letter ...) { ++count; } while(...){...}`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this input string `"a b"` and assume the letter is `c`.

When `i` is `0` you enter the code below because `str[0]`is `a` which doesn't match the letter:

```
    else
    {
        while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0' ) 
            i++;   // Increment i from 0 to 1
    }
```

In the above block, you increment `i` to `1` and then leave the block because `str[1]` is `' '`

In the next main loop, you will again hit this code block:

```
    else
    {
        while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0' ) 
            i++;   // No increment, i.e. i stays at 1
    }
```

but you will **not** increment `i` (as `str[1]` is a space). In other words - `i` remains at `1` and you have an infinite loop.

Maybe you can fix it by this:

```
    else
    {
        while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0' ) 
            i++;   // No increment, i.e. i stays at 1

        // Add this line to remove the spaces
        while (str[i] == ' ') i++;
    }
```